# I can not find correct RegEx to work in Autopsy

Tags: regex, lucene

I'm trying to search for patterns in **Autopsy** that begin with a `#` followed by 8 digits either upper case letters or numbers.
Usually I would do something like `#[A-Z0-9]{8}` or `\23[A-Z0-9]{8}` but unfortunately this does not work.
I found out that Autopsy uses **Lucene Regex Syntax**, but I can not figure out how to change it to make it work.
Any help aprechiated.
Thank you.

Comment: Lucene patterns are auto-anchored at the start/end of string. Does `.*#[A-Z0-9]{8}.*` help?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew No, that doesn"t work either.